# Ubuntu 12.04.1 Server VM doesn't recognize keyboard

Tags: 12.04, server, keyboard, virtualization

I installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 Server on sdb2 with this [iso](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/thank-you?distro=server&bits=64&release=lts).

I selected the `install minimal virtual machine` (after pressing F4) and the installation worked fine.

(The BIOS knows the keyboard and the grub also does as I can choose the boot device.) 
But when I boot into the VM via grub, there is the login screen but I can't type my username.

How can I configure the keyboard manually? Or, how do I get control over the virtual machine?

Comment: Why did you choose `virtual machine`?

Comment: Seriously, i was curious about what'd be different from the normal version. :) (Now i know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I did these steps to solve it:

1.The VM must be in a "Powered Off" state

2.Select the VM in the VirtualBox GUI

3.Click the "Settings" button

4.Go to the menu item "USB" (in here you can add/delete/edit USB Device Filters)

5.On the right-hand side, click the button "Add Filter From Device" and it will list the connected and detected USB devices

6.Select your keyboard from the list

7.Add another filter for your USB mouse

8.Start your VM.

Hope this works! :-)